# How to change path of img for dynamically loaded template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Have a template with button..
Onclick of the button loading another template using Jquery load().

Example:

Template1:

```
<div id='tp1'>
   <button>Load</button>
   <div class="sub"></div>
</div>
```

Template2:

```
   <div id='tp2'>
       <img src='../abc/amd/aa.jpg' class="iPath"/>
       <img src='../edf/dfv/bb.jpg' class="iPath"/>
       <img src='../fgh/vbf/cc.jpg' class="iPath"/>
   </div>
```

Now I need to change the src of tp2 for all the images, but the paths for each image is different.

```
img1 path: ../qwe/afg/aa.jpg
img2 path: ../asd/zvb/bb.jpg
img3 path: ../zxc/qrt/cc.jpg
```

Jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
      $('.sub').load("../abbb.html");
      console.log($('.iPath'));
    });
});
```

But here the iPath is undefined, because the load of the template 2 is not rendered.
How do I know whether the page is successfully loaded or not, so that it will be easy to change the source of the page....

Comment: You need to declare variable `iPath`, it has no relation with loading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a callback to **[load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)**, with required data.

> A callback function that is executed when the request completes.

```
$('.sub').load("../abbb.html",function(data){
    $(data).find('.iPath');
});
```

To change the `src` of image, you need to set the attribute using

```
$('.sub').load("../abbb.html",function(data){
    $(data).find('.iPath').each(function(){
         $(this).attr('src','...')
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you it works but how do I get the img tag from the loaded data, do I need to use data.img

Answer (score 1):

Try Like

```
    $('img').each(function () {
        var src = $(this).attr('src');           
         $(this).attr('src', 'newsrc');           
    });
```

OR

```
    $("#ID > img").each(function() {
      var src = $(this).attr('src');           
      $(this).attr('src', 'newsrc');           
    });
```

Load Using

```
$(function()
{
        $("#div").load("page.html", function(responseText, statusText, xhr)
        {
                if(statusText == "success")
                        alert("Successfully loaded the content!");
                if(statusText == "error")
                        alert("An error occurred: " + xhr.status + " - " + xhr.statusText);
        });
});
```

Comment: How do I know whether the load template is fully loaded or not.

Comment: existance of the element?

Comment: for image tag i have added the code you can use name to differentiate and for load i have edited the answer